# My ESP32 WROOM clone will not register touch sensor when using a 5v power bank with usb cable

Tags: esp32, battery

I have a very simple touch sensor program that works fine and lights an led to show the sensor works; while hooked up to the computer via usb cable it works fine.  When using a power bank with the same usb cable the board lights up but does not read the touch sensor.  I have tried other cables with the same result.

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: What is your schematic? What is this "touch sensor" of which you speak?

Comment: My specific question is about the esp32 touch sensors which are built in touch sensors on the esp32.  Is this normal behavior when trying to use a 5 volt external supply with a usb cable? Has anyone experienced this problem when using the touch sensors? I don't know how to upload the code or a schematic.

Comment: Perhaps this is the wrong forum to ask this question.  I use the Arduino ide to program my esp32 as well as some Arduino boards.

Comment: @JerryG1112 This is the right forum, but I suspect you are looking at the wrong problem.  "Everything" works fine when the board is powered by the PC, but your touch sensor doesn't work (but the board does?) when running off the battery pack.
So whats the difference?  Whats the output of your battery pack (Volts and Amps)?  My first though was there wasn't enough juice.  
A drawing/photo would help, because I'm wondering if you have the touch sensor connected directly to the power supply somehow.  Like wise details of the touch sensor will help, because not all touch sensor are equal :)

Comment: @JerryG1112 - Can you run blink on your board on the battery pack?

Comment: touch doesn't work as well with battery-powered things or things that are outside. for a motorcycle, consider a cheap microwave radar motion detector module.

Comment: I have considered and tried the other types of motion detectors [motion pir, radar, sound, }but they have too many false alarms. i am only trying to prevent gasoline theft.  My last resort will be laser alarm but it is so difficult to setup. Yes blink works.  Gil has provided the path to a solution, but i have yet to complete it.  My current problem is using a larger cap sensor than a wire because I cannot differentiate the touch/no touch states with even a kitchen pot or pan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to explain but your problem in not unique. I hope this helps. It is your ground reference. When connected to the computer which is grounded either/or a ground wire or capacitive coupling to earth. Your body is capacitively connected to ground that way and when you touch the switch it is recognized.  To make it work with the battery pack you need to couple to the person touching it. You can do that capacitively by adding a ground plain to your circuit. This can be a conductive plate that will capacitively couple the ground to the atmosphere or any other practical means.

Comment: I am using Touch0  which is on GPIO 4.  The led is on  GPIO22 as digital output pin.  I uploaded a blink sketch and it does work on the battery.  The board powers onbaord led under battery power but will not respond to a touch, so I think Gil has the right solution.  i just don't know how to make a conductive plate. Perhaps if I connect the touch wire to my motorcycle it will work as I intend.  (a burglar alarm)

Comment: Anything conductive would work. If you power it from the motorcycle the ground plane becomes the frame no other connections needed unless the electrical system is isolated but I doubt it.

Comment: I will try that solution tomorrow.  Thank you for the help.